# Three hots and a neutral in a recessed light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I was wiring a Lightolier recessed light (model 1000AICM) and I noticed that the junction box has three black wires and one neutral. I've never encountered this before. I conjecture the following: the three black wires are actually connected and are there only to facilitate daisy chaining of lights. So if I'm wiring a single light, I should connect hot to any one of the black wires and simply connect the other two together with a small wire nut.

Am I right? If so, why aren't there three neutrals, too?

[image]

Comment: Is one of the black wires black because it's taped black?  If so is there a wall switch for this fixture location?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: They are bona fide black wires.

Comment: Can you see where the wires go inside the housing?

Comment: You state three "HOTS" is that do to the fact all three measure or indicate voltage on them or just because they are black.  Traveler wires going to and from lights or switches can be black but are not "HOT" coming from a breaker.

Comment: Is your your house is wired with conduit? The white looks taped so it was identified as a neutral. The wires look to have a black plastic restraint. If it is plastic is the ground is routed in the pipe also? It looks like it could be the light is fed with a hot and neutral then a switch leg run on the 2 additional blacks. if this is the case only 1 of the wires will be hot. the other 2 go to the switch. If this is correct connect the hot to 1 of the other black wires. the unused black to the black on the light and the white to white. if your light has a ground connect it to the box.

Comment: Is the photo showing the wires coming out of the housing (and into the junction box), or is it showing wires feeding into the junction box from the circuit?

Comment: Can you show me a closer view of the fitting where the wires enter the box?

Comment: The picture shows all of the wires from the fixture itself, none from the circuit. The pictures shows a new fixture so none of the wires have been modified. To answer spicetrader's question, I'm only calling them "hot" because they are black.